# Does anybody have the complete Sanskrit version of Jayatirtha's Padyamala?

Tags: rituals, puja, resource

I have come across the abridged English version of Sri Jayatirtha's Padyamala. It is a Sanskrit Nitya pooja text that is based on Madhwacharya's tantrasara sangrama.

I am looking for its Sanskrit version with a possible English translation if available.

Comment: Here is link of  PDF file of  Sri Jayatirtha's Padyamala in Sanskrit. It appears that first we need to sign up and then we will be able to download the file - https://www.a108.net/file/271-books-jayatirtha-книги-джаятиртха/ - Will post the answer if the files contains sanskrit pdf.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Got the book from there. Thank you. You may post it as the answer and i can accept it.

Comment: It's nice to know that you got the book. I will Post it as a brief answer in some time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Sri Jayatîrtha**](http://www.dvaita.org/scholars/jayatirtha/) or Jayateertharu (also known as Teekācharya) c. 1365 – c. 1388   was a Hindu philosopher, dialectician, polemicist and the sixth pontiff of Madhvacharya Peetha. Sri Jayatîrtha is considered to be one of the most important seers in the history of **Dvaita school of thought** on account of his sound elucidations of the works of Madhvacharya.

He spent much of his physical life in Mangalvedhe, which is about 12 miles south-east of Pandharpur (in modern Maharashtra, and home of Lord Vitthala). He was born in the family of a Brahmin king, and was heir to the throne.
 He gave  Tattvavâda its place in modern Vedanta , through his works.

---

As you have requested here is Sri Jayatirtha's [**Padyamala**](https://www.a108.net/file/271-books-jayatirtha-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%85%D0%B0/) in Sanskrit.  It's a PDF file which we can download after registering to the site.

---

[image]